# Changing User Agent in Chromium browsers on Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

Is it possible to change Chrome, Bromite or Brave browser user agent? I am on Android 10 AOSP rom. Rooted device.

It can be done easily on Android Firefox or Kiwi browser with addons and extensions. But what about the chromium browsers which dont support extension.

Comment: Hello. What are you trying to accomplish by changing user-agent?